# Chrome and Safari Calculate Margins Incorrectly When Child is Wider Than Parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, webkit

Here's an example (an alert box will pop up with the results). Run this in Firefox then Chrome and/or Safari

http://jsfiddle.net/QeaVM/

Notice how FF correctly includes the left and right margins in the calculation of outerWidth. Notice how Safari/Chrome incorrectly state that the outerWidth of #Container is equal to that of #Frame.

Also, notice that Safari/Chrome incorrectly report #Container's margin-right as a negative number when it is explicity set to 300px

Is this a bug in web-kit or jquery?

Comment: The child doesn't need to be wider than the parent for this bug to occur, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the page in the inspectors for both browsers (ignoring javascript completely) you can see the same differences (so that rules out jQuery).

It does seem odd and appears to be reported bug with webkit.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13343

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24511

The comments mention a workaround "A workaround is setting the element to display:none (or inline-block), measuring the margin then setting display back to block."

Comment: Crappy work around but at least there is one... thanks for the leg work!