# jquery hero slider only working in firefox

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I am using a hero slider on the following page that allows user to change between 5 slides.

It works as it should in Firefox but isn't working in chrome or safari and I can't seem to find the cause.  Any help spotting it would be greatly appreciated.

http://zeccio.com/clients/PFRB/index.php/home

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is quite bizarre...

Comment: The browsers are apparently interpreting the positioning of that "slide-inner" element very, very differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may answer your question: [Chrome and Safari Calculate Margins Incorrectly When Child is Wider Than Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074441/chrome-and-safari-calculate-margins-incorrectly-when-child-is-wider-than-parent)